# Inject new inline styles to a React HOC product

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Using a common HOC pattern like so works beautifully. However, there are times when you really don't want a component to be wrapped and just want the same component you passed in extended a bit. That's what I'm struggling with here.

**Wrapper HOC**

```
const flexboxContainerStyles = {
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'row',
  backgroundColor: 'pink',
}

let WrapInFlexContainer = FlexChild => class extends React.Component {
  render(){

    return (
      <div className="flexContainer" style={flexboxContainerStyles} >
        <FlexChild {...this.props} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const Button = (props) => <button>{props.txt}</button>
let FlexButton = WrapInFlexContainer(Button);
```

The following examples result in a button with no style attributes.

**Example 1.1: pass-through via createClass**

```
function hocPassThroughViaClass(Component) {
  return React.createClass({
    render: function() {
     return <Component {...this.props} style={flexboxContainerStyles}/>;
    }
  });
}
```

**Example 1.2 pass-through via direct render**

```
let hocPassThroughViaRender = Element => class extends React.Component {
  render(){   
    return <Element {...this.props} className="flexContainer" style={flexboxContainerStyles} />
  }
}
```

**Example 2: create**

```
function hocCreate(Component) {
  return React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      const modifiedProps = Object.assign({}, {...this.props}, {...flexboxContainerStyles});
      return React.createElement(Component, { ...modifiedProps });
    }
  });
}
```

**Example 3: clone**

```
function hocClone(Component) {
  return React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      const modifiedProps = Object.assign({}, {...this.props}, {...flexboxContainerStyles});
      return React.cloneElement(<Component {...modifiedProps } />);
    }
  });
}

// render examples
let HOCPassThroughViaClassButton = hocPassThroughViaClass(Button); // 1.1
let HOCPassThroughRenderButton = hocPassThroughViaRender(Button); // 1.2 
let HOCCreatedButton = hocCreate(Button); // 2
let HOCClonedButton = hocClone(Button); // 3
```

From a couple of points I'm seeing here and there across the web, it doesn't seem like it's possible to return the same `Component` if it is an only child.

See: https://github.com/threepointone/glamor/blob/master/docs/createElement.md

https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/trying-to-do-a-reactdom-render-a-el-replacing-the-el-not-appending-to-it/2681/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The following examples result in a button with no style attributes.

Isn't this happening because you're not passing the style prop along? Wouldn't this be fixed by doing this:

```
const Button = (props) => <button style={props.style}>{props.txt}</button>
```

Update:

HOCs don't magically apply props to children of the wrapped component, meaning that low level elements like `<button />` or `<div />` need props passed to them one way or another. You're passing props to `<Button />`, not `<button />`. You can however make an HOC that takes a basic element and adds whatever to it.

```
let hoc = element => (
  class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      let { children, ...props } = this.props
      return React.createElement(
        element, 
        { ...props, style: flexboxContainerStyles },
        children,
      )
    }
  }
)
```

Usage:

```
let FlexButton = hoc('button')

let App = props => <FlexButton>{props.txt}</FlexButton>
```

**[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/61154/)**

That being said, you're not changing the API of the base component by passing along known props like style and className along. In fact it's a great way to make components more reusable *without* specifying implementation details.

```
// good!
let Button = ({ children, ...props }) => <button {...props}>{children}</button>
```

Comment: Yes, but then that defeats the purpose. The goal is that the component passed as a param doesn't need to be aware of the function or have its own API changed.

Comment: Updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thanks for a solid explanation.

Comment: One thing I'm noticing after I have had some time to think, is that I feel like accepting any props object blindly is a code smell.

Comment: Sure I agree with that. a) use `PropTypes`, b) pass along "known" props like style, classname (anything that a DOM element can actually use)